# How do I locally host the webbrowser Virtual Machine here: http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Tags: javascript, operating-system

I don't know much of Javascript, and I want to host the web browser integrated Linux (which can be found [here](http://bellard.org/jslinux/)). Reason being I am not always connected to the net, would like to know how it works. No disrespect of the author's license intended.

I tried copying sources of the three files (`term.js`, `cpux86.js` and the HTML file itself) into a folder, and running the HTML, and it doesn't work.

Any way around to make it work?
Also: if it doesn't work, why is it? The directory structure is copied by me and is almost the same.

PS: I also used Javascript deobfuscator addon for Firefox, but that did not help much either. I did indent all the code to make it more readable, but it's still not understandable :P

Comment: My plans are to install Lynx inside the system and open the same website from the virtual machine. That would be really meta. (Considering even GCC is not installed, it is going to be very hard) Comments on that would be appreciated too.

Comment: If you don't know much javascript figuring out Patrice's js wrapper for linux is not going to be easy

Comment: I know. I badly need some hardcore programmers to make my 9hr dream (either of running it locally or going meta with it) come true.

Comment: @Anuj - there is no network interface implemented in jslinux, so unless your're going to copy the source for lynx by hand i don't know how you will do this.

Comment: You can't copy paste an uuencoded document either. I was planning on writing a keyboard emulator to type the uuencoded tar into the machine (Just because you can't copy-paste text)

Comment: i've just upvoted you only for the link you provided... It's awesome :-D

Comment: Grooveek: It will be awesomer if we actually get to know how that thing exactly works. Check Richard's link to the documentation below. Nice place to start with.

Answer (score 1):

The JS code itself is not a "Linux clone", it's a propper x86 Virtual Machine **loading** a Linux kernel.

As such you need *at least* the file containing the compiled Linux kernel for it to work correctly.

Checking the source shows that (at least) 3 files are loadded from `cpux86.js`, which are: `vmlinux26.bin` (the Linux kernel), `root.bin` (probably the root file system) and `linuxstart.bin` (this seems to be the bootloader).

Comment: Right. The image (as my friend on IRC just found out through chrome-network-analyzer) is around 1.2MB. How do I save those bin files from Mozilla Firefox (lsof?) EDIT: Firefox from the host machine. EDIT: Are they stored somewhere in /proc? (Linux host)

Comment: @Anuj - you really should read the technical notes http://bellard.org/jslinux/tech.html, they are specially compiled versions. You will have to download them using wget or similar

Comment: @Richard That one deserved an upvote. I will get back when I read this documentation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

These are the files you will need:

- http://bellard.org/jslinux/linuxstart.bin
- http://bellard.org/jslinux/vmlinux26.bin
- http://bellard.org/jslinux/root.bin
- http://bellard.org/jslinux/cpux86.js
- http://bellard.org/jslinux/term.js

Throw them in along with this file into a folder and you're good to go:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript PC Emulator</title>
<style>
.term {
    font-family: courier,fixed,swiss,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    background: #000000;
}

.termReverse {
    color: #000000;
    background: #00ff00;
}
#note {
    font-size: 12px;
}
#copyright {
    font-size: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
<script src="term.js"></script>
<script src="cpux86.js"></script>
<div id="copyright">&copy; 2011 Fabrice Bellard - <a href="tech.html">Technical notes</a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to given answers you can try to look at the way I am hosting jslinux on a local server in my jsmodem project at http://github.com/ewiger/jsmodem (allows Internet connectivity).

If you have python installed just start the local web server as

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't inspected the page but all you need to do is make sure that all assets required are referenced correctly. The js assets are referenced in the page, the linux binaries are loaded from within those scripts somewhere. You're going to have to dig through them and find where, and change the URLs appropriately.

And as for figuring out how the emulation etc works, this project is quite a hacking feat, so good luck :)