# Running JSLinux in Rhino

Tags: rhino, envjs

For the fun of it, I tried running JSLinux in Rhino using envjs and it doesn't seem to throw any errors, nor does it seem to work.

As mentioned here: [How do I locally host the webbrowser Virtual Machine here: http://bellard.org/jslinux/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032731/how-do-i-locally-host-the-webbrowser-virtual-machine-here-http-bellard-org-jsl/6037809#6037809), I first downloaded all the files and ensured that it opens up fine in a browser. Then I got to trying it out in rhino.

Here is the interaction:

```
$ rhino
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2010 01 20
js> load('env.js')
[  Envjs/1.6 (Rhino; U; Linux i386 2.6.32-31-generic-pae; en-US; rv:1.7.0.rc2)   Resig/20070309 PilotFish/1.2.13  ]
js> window.location = 'emul.html';
```

There is some high CPU usage and then it seems to be doing nothing.

Is there some way to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Rhino does not support [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays%20typed%20arrays), which is required for jslinux to run.

Answer (score 0):

> "I first downloaded all the files and
>   ensured that it opens up fine in a
>   browser. "

Did it work? I did this too, but Chrome said :

> Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for HTTP.

then I copy the files to my Apache www folder, and view it with localhost, it finally works.
So I think that you may have to modify the JS file with the Ajax part(it use Ajax to load 3 files like vmlinux26.bin etc)

Comment: I just checked again. It works in FF4 but does not work in Chromium.